# Definition of galois extensions in rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

Im reading the Paper "Galois Theory of commutative Ring: A historical perspective" of Sharon Zhou availbel as PDF in google. Im troubling with one of the first definitions:
We say that $R \to T$ is a $G$-Galois extension iff the maps:

$ i:R \to T^G$ and $h: T\otimes T \to \prod_G T$ are both isomorphisms.

I have several questions to this definition. Firstly, how does the map $i$ work in general? Than the first condition says that $R$ is a fixed ring, so its basically the same thing, as in Galois Theory for Fields. Why do I need for rings also the second condition? Does somebody have an example of an map which suffices the first but not the second condition, and an argument why this extension should not be galois?
In his paper the author writes, that $h$ measueres the extent to which the extension is ramified. What does this mean? And why should a galois extension me unramified?

A last question. For fields Galois theory starts with saying what an algebraic and finite extension is. For rings we have analogous notions like integral and finite ring extensions. But it seems to me that this notions dont appear in the theory of Galois Theory in rings. Is there a specific reason, why we dont use this definitions as starting points and is there still maybe a connection (e.g is it true $R\to T$ is a Galois extension, iff this is a integral and finite map?)

Answer (score 2):

We don't care of the map $i$,
simply assume that $G$ is a finite subgroup of $Aut(T)$, $R=T^G$ and $T\otimes_{T^G}T \cong \prod_{g\in G} T$.

Try $T^G=\Bbb{C}$, $T = \Bbb{C}[x]/(x^2), G = \{1,g,g^2,g^3\}, g(a+xb)=a+ixb$. Then $T\otimes_{T^G}T\cong \Bbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ is a free $T^G$ module of rank $4$, and it has only one prime ideal (the ideal of nilpotents which is $(x,y)$) so it is not isomorphic to $T^4$.

$T/T^G$ should not be said Galois for example because $x$ is a root of $X^2 \in T^G[X]$ of degree $2$ whereas $x$ has $4$ conjugates.